# Given a covarince matrix, generate a Gaussian random variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

Given a `M x M` desired covariance, `R`, and a desired number of sample vectors, `N` calculate a `N x M` Gaussian random vector, `X` in vanilla MATLAB (i.e. can't use `r = mvnrnd(MU,SIGMA,cases)`).

Not really sure how to tackle this, usually you need a covariance AND mean to [generate a Gaussian random variable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html). I think `sqrtm` and `chol` could be useful.

Comment: Yes, just take the Cholesky decomposition of `R`, and pre-multiply an i.i.d. (i.e. `randn`) matrix.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @OliCharlesworth: http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/

Comment: @LuisMendo, I think there is a mistake when he calculate using eigenvector decomposition but the `chol` transformation looks good

Comment: Note that correlation matrix ≠ covariance matrix. A correlation matrix is a normalized covariance matrix. If you use `chol`, you should make sure that you're using correlation matrices. Otherwise there's `cholcov` for the more general case.

Answer (score 3):

If you  have access to the MATLAB statistics toolbox you can type `edit mvnrnd` in MATLAB to see their solution.

```
[T p] = chol(sigma);
if m1 == c
  mu = mu';
end
mu = mu(ones(cases,1),:);
r = randn(cases,c) * T + mu;
```

It feels almost like cheating to point this out, but editing MATLAB's source is very useful to understand things in general. You can also search for `mvnrnd.m` on google if you don't have the toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
% Gaussian mean and covariance
d = 2;             % number of dimensions
mu = rand(1,d);
sigma = rand(d,d); sigma = sigma*sigma';

% generate 100 samples from above distribution
num = 100;
X = mvnrnd(mu, sigma, num);

% plot samples (only for 2D case)
scatter(X(:,1), X(:,2), 'filled'), hold on
ezcontour(@(x,y) mvnpdf([x y], mu, sigma), xlim(), ylim())
title('X~N(\mu,\sigma)')
xlabel('X_1'), ylabel('X_2')
```

[image: 2d gaussian samples]

The above code uses functions from the Statistics toolbox ([mvnrnd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html) and [mvnpdf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html)). If you don't have access to it, consider these replacements (using the same concepts mentioned by others):

```
mvnrnd = @(mu,S,num) bsxfun(@plus, randn(num,numel(mu))*cholcov(S), mu);

mvnpdf = @(x,mu,S) exp(-0.5*(x-mu)*(S\(x-mu)')) / sqrt((2*pi)^d*det(S));
```

[image: multivariate normal distribution PDF]

Comment: of interest: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/02/08/use-the-cholesky-transformation-to-correlate-and-uncorrelate-variables/